# Connect with an AD user to a ubuntu Machine

Tags: samba, pam, active-directory, kerberos

I try to log on under a ubuntu machine with an AD user via the GUI lightdm , but access is denied with "invalid password , please try again "

My machine has been added in the AD : net ads join -U administrator, I visualize the users and groups with wbinfo -u and wbinfo -g

Furthermore,i visualize the user from AC

```
  id jn
   uid=10019(jn) gid=10002(utilisateurs du domaine) ....
```

cat /etc/samba/smb.conf

```
[global]
workgroup = AAA
realm = AAA.LOCAL
netbios name = ubuntu
security = ads
encrypt passwords = yes
password server = XXX.XXX.XXX
idmap uid = 10000-20000
idmap gid = 10000-20000 
winbind enum groups = yes
winbind enum users = yes
winbind use default domain = yes
template homedir = /data/commun
```

cat /etc/krb5.conf

```
[libdefaults]
default_realm = AAA.LOCAL
dns_lookup_realm = false
dns_lookup_kdc = true
ticker_lifetile = 24h
default_tgs_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 rc4-hmac des-cbc-md5
default_tkt_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 rc4-hmac des-cbc-md5
permitted_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 rc4-hmac des-cbc-crc-md5

krb4_config = /etc/krb.conf
krb4_realms = /etc/krb.realms
kdc_timesync = 1
ccache_type = 4
forwardable = true
proxiable = true

[realms]
PA8.LOCAL = {
kdc = XXX.XXX.XXX
admin_server = XXX.XXX.XXX
default_domain = AAA.LOCAL
 }

 [domain_realm]
.XXX.local = XXX.LOCAL
 XXX.local = XXX.LOCAL
```

cat /etc/pam.d/common-account

```
account sufficient      pam_winbind.so
account sufficient      pam_unix.so
```

cat /etc/pam.d/common-auth

```
auth sufficient pam_winbind.so
auth sufficient pam_unix.so nullok_secure use_first_pass
auth required pam_deny.so
```

cat /etc/pam.d/common-session

```
session required pam_unix.so
session required pam_mkhomedir.so umask=0022 skel=/etc/skel
```

So, i don't know where is the the problem, why i can't to connect a user from AD in ubuntu's machine

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question. But it seems better to provide an answer to an old question than ask one myself just to answer it with what I finally got working!

Have you tried `sssd`? I'm doing this without `winbind`.

**/etc/sssd/sssd.conf**

```
[sssd]
services = nss, pam
config_file_version = 2
domains = MBA.AC.UK

[domain/MBA.AC.UK]
id_provider = ad
access_provider = ad

override_homedir = /home/%d/%u
default_shell = /bin/bash
```

**/etc/krb5.conf** didn't require anything other than the **Default realm** specified in

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure krb5-config
```

**smb.conf** is unchanged (I mount user shares via `libpam_mount`--which, however, I can tell you up front will screw with `lightdm`. Perhaps [pam / ad issue with lightdm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/938156/pam-ad-issue-with-lightdm?rq=1) would help with that.)

I don't *think* I modified any of the `/etc/pam.d/` files beyond the auto-configuration when `sssd` was installed.

**/etc/pam.d/common-account**

```
account [success=1 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]        pam_unix.so 
account requisite                       pam_deny.so
account required                        pam_permit.so
account sufficient                      pam_localuser.so 
account [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore]    pam_sss.so
```

**/etc/pam.d/common-auth**

```
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_sss.so use_first_pass
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
auth    required                        pam_permit.so
auth    optional        pam_mount.so 
auth    optional                        pam_cap.so
```

**/etc/pam.d/common-session**

```
session [default=1]                     pam_permit.so
session requisite                       pam_deny.so
session required                        pam_permit.so
session optional                        pam_umask.so
session required        pam_unix.so 
session optional                        pam_sss.so 
session optional        pam_mount.so 
session optional        pam_systemd.so 
session optional                        pam_mkhomedir.so
```