# pam / ad issue with lightdm

Tags: samba, lightdm, pam, active-directory, kerberos

im having issues logging in the desktop via AD with my current setup with sssd, kerberos, samba, and AD. heres the output of the auth.log file. it seems that pam and lightdm aren't working well with each other. the odd thing is that i can su - user@domain.org from cli and run commands such as id or getent passwd to return users in my AD.

`Jul 20 11:14:08 lx004109 lightdm: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet5.so
Jul 20 11:14:12 lx004109 lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "user@domain"
Jul 20 11:14:15 lx004109 lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=:0 ruser= rhost=  user=user@domain
Jul 20 11:14:15 lx004109 lightdm: pam_sss(lightdm:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=:0 ruser= rhost= user=user@domain
Jul 20 11:14:15 lx004109 lightdm: pam_sss(lightdm:auth): received for user user@domain: 6 (Permission denied)
Jul 20 11:14:16 lx004109 lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Jul 20 11:14:16 lx004109 lightdm: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so`

here is my sssd.conf file

```
    [sssd]
services = nss, pam
config_file_version = 2
domains = KQED.ORG

[domain/KQED.ORG]
ad_gpo_map_interactive = +polkit-1. +unity, +lightdm
id_provider  = ad
access_provider = ad
ad_domain = my.domain.org
default_shell = /bin/bash
krb5_realm = KQED.ORG
dyndns_update = true
dyndsn_refresh_interval = 43200
dyndns_update_ptr = true
dyndns_ttl = 3600
auth_provider = ad
chpass_provider = ad
access_provider = ad
ldap_schema = ad
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
cache_credentials = True
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = False
fallback_homedir = /home/%u
override_homedir = /home/%d/%u
enumerate = true
```

any ideas out there? ive seen a couple of articles claim this below is a work around to add to sssd but it doesnt seem to apply to my situation.

`ad_gpo_map_interactive = +unity, +polkit-1`

Answer (score 0):

after troubleshooting for many hours i was able to find two attributes to add to my current SSSD.conf allowing pam_sss & pam_unix to respond to sss & active directory. fixing AD desktop gui logins. `ad_enable_gc = False` & `ad_gpo_access_control = permissive`

```
[sssd]
services = nss, pam
config_file_version = 2
domains = Webdomain.ORG

[domain/Webdomain.ORG]
ad_enable_gc = False
ad_gpo_map_interactive = +unity
ad_gpo_access_control = permissive
```